# How do I pass values in vector to a function that takes multiple parameters

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I am new to programming and need help with loops.

I have a vector named data that is filled with however many numbers

```
vector<int> data;
```

I also have the following function

```
addEdge(graph, src, dest, weight)
```

the numbers in data are specifically ordered so that  the pattern [src, dest, weight] is upheld. I want to start from data[2] and loop forward until data.size() is reached and there are no more numbers left in data.

for example, I want to create a loop that does this:

```
addEdge(graph, data[2], data[3] , data[4]);
addEdge(graph, data[5], data[6], data[7]);
addEdge(graph, data[8], data[9], data[10]);
```

etc.. until data.size() is reached. Is this possible? I tried a for loop and while loop but kept getting stuck, ex:

```
for (int i=2; i< data.size(); i++ ){

       addEdge(graph, data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]);
     }
```

Or should I just make a file like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTp88.png)

and read each line and for 3 integers and pass as parameters in the function? How would I do this in c++? Or should I use another type of loop? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you "get stuck" with your `for` loop?  (Based on your example, it looks like `i+=3` might be a better increment than `i++`.)

Comment: thank you for  your help.. I don't consider myself to be a programmer lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in right direction, just that you are missing out on a `for` loop, just replace `i++` in your `for` loop with `i+=3`, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hard code the striding.  Of course, this blows up if `data.size()` is not divisible by 3.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size()/3; ++i)
{
  addEdge(graph, data[3*i], data[3*i+1], data[3*i+2]);
}
```

Comment: Did you see that OP start counting with i=2?

Comment: @Amadeus Yes, but then he went up all the way to `data.size()` instead of `data.size()-3`.  In my opinion, my design is better and less error prone.